Google Cloud CDN json resource ETag missing from response headers
The ETags are missing from the response headers. Currently, I am using Google Cloud CDN to deliver the resources from Google Cloud Storage (bucket). When the resource is read directly from the bucket, the ETag is present, however, if the resource is obtained through the CDN the ETag is missing.
I am using:

google cloud cdn
google cloud storage

Here is a sample list of response headers of a resource that doesn't include the Etag header:

There are a number of other headers present but I do not believe them to be important for the matter at hand.
The below screenshot, shows the Cloud CDN Cache settings:

This is the metadata of an individual document within the bucket:

The question is, is there a Google Cloud CDN setting that is preventing the caching or ETags from showing in the response headers?
If any more information is needed to make this a bit more clear, please let me know so I can try and provide it.

Have you tried setting the cache control on your origin server? Which technology are you using for your origin application server like (Apache / Nginx )? If possible can you update the question with these details.

@DharaniDharGolladasari The origin server is neither one. It is a Load Balancer pointing to Google Cloud Storage.

Can you try setting the cache mode to “Use origin settings on Cache-Control headers”. Because “Force cache all content” unconditionally caches all successful responses that might lead to overriding the Etags.

@DharaniDharGolladasari If I set it to that option, does that mean I will have to provide the headers individually for each request? If that is the case, what should the headers be? Cache-Control: ?

@DharaniDharGolladasari a bit of an advancement, etags are being provided for files with sizes of <1kb and for those that are >1kb it doesn't provide the etag response headers, any idea if that is a setting that can be changed?

Just a hunch here, but I see that you have Dynamic Compression enabled and the content-type you have listed is application/json which is a compressible object type. I am suspecting that Cloud CDN is compressing the object which is altering the object and could be stripping your etag value. As a test, perhaps turn off Dynamic Compression to see if the etags bleed through. If the etag is visible after turning off the compression, you have your answer.
The Cloud CDN service will use the last modified time in lieu of an etag so there is no risk of having out of date content.

This was indeed the root cause. Thank you for the reply. I would also like to point out that we switched to a different strategy, instead of relying on the eTag and having If-None-Match request header, we now use the If-Modified-Since header and checking the last-updated date that is always present within the response headers.
